# What metric to calculate correlation between average user ratings of products?

Tags: r, correlation, spearman-rho

What's the best method to see if there's a strong correlation between two types of ratings on a product level (product $1, 2, \dots, n$) where each product has ratings of type '$a$' and '$b$'?

For the paired averages of ratings (of type $a$ and $b$) on a product level, would it be biasing my results if I filter out products with small number of ratings per type of rating, or low standard error in either average of ratings, or a combination of both?

Which would be best: Pearson's or Spearman's?

What's the most valid way to observe a potential existence of a relationship?

Also, would said method allow for more explanatory factor variables, like product type?

The overall goal is to see if there is a correlated (or non-random) relationship between the two averages on a product level (since they're what's surfaced on the marketplace).

Comment: This may help: [Is it meaningful to calculate Pearson or Spearman correlation between two Boolean vectors?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103801/is-it-meaningful-to-calculate-pearson-or-spearman-correlation-between-two-boolea)

Comment: Also see [How to choose between Pearson and Spearman correlation?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8071/how-to-choose-between-pearson-and-spearman-correlation?rq=1).