# Binary data correlation with many variables

Tags: correlation, binary-data

I'm struggling with something that at first sight seemed simple to me but turned out no to be. I have a big df (112 samples x 58 characteristics), these characteristics are all binary (presence/absence, yes/no) coded as 1/0. Here's a random example:

```
condition<-c(rep(0:1,20))
char1<-sample(0:1,20,replace = T)
char2<-sample(0:1,20,replace = T)
char3<-sample(0:1,20,replace = T)
char4<-sample(0:1,20,replace = T)
char5<-sample(0:1,20,replace = T)
char6<-sample(0:1,20,replace = T)
char7<-sample(0:1,20,replace = T)
char8<-sample(0:1,20,replace = T)
char9<-sample(0:1,20,replace = T)
char10<-sample(0:1,20,replace = T)

df<-data.frame(condition,char1,char2,char3,char4,char5,char6,char7,char8,char9,char10)
```

I would like to see if there is some sort of correlation between condition_0 or condition_1 and any of the analysed characteristics.

I've thought of generating a proportion table and using a Chisq:

```
prop<-prop.table(data.matrix(df),2)
chi<-chisq.test(prop)
```

but I'm getting X-squared = NaN (with the real dataset, the example here gives an actual output). So I'm thinking this is not the right approach.
I've also tried a logistic regression but the model doesn't converge and it also seems somewhat odd.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this? I'll be happy with just a method name.

Many many thanks!

Comment: If two variables are both (0.1) you can measure agreement in various ways and you can measure correlation so long as there is variability on both variables. These are not the same question. For example, if both variables are identically 0 or identically 1, agreement is perfect but correlation is not defined. Which do you want, or do you want something else?

Comment: Hi @NickCox!
 
 Thanks for the reply and the clarification of these two concepts. I would like to test for correlation.

Comment: Then see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103801/is-it-meaningful-to-calculate-pearson-or-spearman-correlation-between-two-boolea for more advice.