Measure of correlation between binary sequences that were generated using a gaussian process
To perform an experiment, I need to construct a collection of $n$ binary sequences of length $T.$
Example consisting of $n=3$ and $T=20$:
$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&1&0&0&1&0&1&1&0&1&0&0&1&1&0&0&1&0&1 \\
0&1&0&1&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1 \\
1&0&1&0&0&1&1&0&0&1&0&1&1&0&1&0&0&1&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$
Each row in the above matrix was created by sampling from a Gaussian process with a covariance matrix of shape 20 x 20 and then using a threshold (based on a predetermined percentage of 1s), I convert them to a binary sequence. Note that this threshold can vary for each sequence. Now, I would like to find the cross-correlation between these three (or $n$) sequences. My intent is to create $x$ out of $n$ sequences using Gaussian processes with a similar kernel function to induce correlation. Having a cross-correlation measure would help me note behaviors of a certain algorithm when run on each of these sequences.

Pearson correlation is perfectly well defined so long some values of either argument are 0 and some are 1 (because all values being 0 or all values being 1 would blow up the result). Whether this is quite what you need or want is a harder question. But see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103801/is-it-meaningful-to-calculate-pearson-or-spearman-correlation-between-two-boolea

"I created the sequence above using a Gaussian process with a unique covariance matrix for each sequence." That sentence does not at all make it clear how you did this. Nor what any of the joint distributions are.

@MichaelHardy I made edits to make it clearer. Sorry for the earlier sentence (english is not my first language)

Unless your covariance matrix has a special structure, and assuming the threshold is independent of the data in each series, this will require numerical calculations (as I remarked in one of your earlier questions.)

@whuber My threshold is dependent on the data, coz I mark data above for example, 80th quantile as 1 and rest 0. In this case, how do I go about calculating the correlation? Or in general, when I can't assume that the sequence is generated by iid Bernouilli process, how do I calculate correlation between two binary sequences?

There's nothing special about binary sequences for calculating correlation coefficients.  But setting the quantile based on the data looks like it complicates everything, which inclines me even more towards a numerical solution than before.

@whuber Forgive me but I don't understand what you mean by numerical solution

The correlation coefficient ultimately is an integral.  There are myriad ways to compute and approximate integrals, including Monte Carlo simulation and various methods of "quadrature."
